# SwiftUI list over Set from core data

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to iterate over a Set of data coming from core data.
Action is another ManagedEntity

```
@NSManaged public var action: Set<Action>?
```

Action

```
public class Action: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Action> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Action>(entityName: "Action")
    }

    @NSManaged public var identifer: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var place: NSSet?
    
}
```

I tried different option with List, but no luck.

Any idea ?
Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Can you show the variants you tried?

Comment: Well its November now and still no straight forward answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct ContentView: View {

  @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
  var actions : FetchedResults<Action>

  var body: some View {
    List() {
      ForEach (actions){ action in
        Text(action.name ?? "no Name")
      }
    }
  }
}
```